# How to combine F-bounded polymorphism with associated types in Scala?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, traits, associated-types, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have a trait called `Graphlike` for things that work as a graph. Notably, one of the properties I want to have is that the method `g.subgraph(Set(1, 2, 3))` would return a subgraph of the same type with just the vertices 1, 2 and 3. Apparently, this means that I want F-bounded polymorphism and that `Graphlike` looks something like this:

```scala
trait Graphlike[A <: Graphlike[A]] {
  type Vertex

  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[Vertex]): A
}
```

I also have a trait representing an automaton with associated types for edges and vertices. I want it to behave like a graph. Simplified, it looks like this:

```scala
trait Automaton extends Graphlike[Automaton] {
  type State
  type Vertex = State

  def states: Iterable[State]
  def initialState: State
}
```

This almost works. However, Scala's type system gets confused when I try to mix the two and do something useful with the result:

```scala
class UsesAutomataAsGraphs(val aut: Automaton with Graphlike[Automaton]) {
  aut.subgraph(Set(aut.initialState)).subgraph(Set(aut.initialState))
}
```

gives an error like:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/albin/Downloads/example/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /Users/albin/Downloads/example/src/main/scala/example/Example.scala:21:56: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : UsesAutomataAsGraphs.this.aut.State
[error]  required: _1.State where val _1: Automaton
[error]   aut.subgraph(Set(aut.initialState)).subgraph(Set(aut.initialState))
```

How do I get Scala to understand that the two associated types are the same in all derived objects?

Comment: Guess you mean dependent types

Comment: @cchantep https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#An_associated_type_synonym_example

Comment: Thx but for me in Scala that's a dependent type

Comment: For the record, I learnt the notion [from rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.0/book/2018-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html?highlight=associated,types#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution seems to be this. Just make sure that subgraph returns the same type with `this.type` and you're good to go. There's no need for `A` - it just adds additional complexity as you try to prove that `A` is the type of `this`.

```
trait Graphlike {
  type Vertex

  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[Vertex]): this.type
}

trait Automaton extends Graphlike {
  type State
  type Vertex = State

  def states: Iterable[State]
  def initialState: State
}

class UsesAutomataAsGraphs(val aut: Automaton) {
  aut.subgraph(Set(aut.initialState)).subgraph(Set(aut.initialState))
}
```

In Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zMtde7VISKi18LdPXO6Ytw

---

Having `State` be a type parameter also worked for me. Note that in `UsesAutomataAsGraphs`, if you use `A <: Automaton[_]` (a wildcard), it doesn't work, because `State` could be anything. The compiler wants your assurance that the returned `Automaton` will have the same `State` type (because it's unbounded, and other classes extending `Automaton` could define it differently).

```
trait Graphlike[A <: Graphlike[A]] {
  type Vertex

  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[Vertex]): A
}

trait Automaton[State] extends Graphlike[Automaton[State]] {
  type Vertex = State

  def states: Iterable[State]
  def initialState: State
}

class UsesAutomataAsGraphs[S](val aut: Automaton[S]) {
  aut.subgraph(Set(aut.initialState)).subgraph(Set(aut.initialState))
}
```

Link to Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RolPc3ggTxeZ2tUqdXKNEQ

---

It also works if you define `subgraph` as such:

```
def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[_ >: Vertex]): this.type
```

Because it's contravariant, even if `Vertex` is different in different classes and/or traits, it'll work.

Link to Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fz509HEpTBGoJGaJxLziBQ

Comment: Thank you! It does, as I just realised, and that was a typo. However, this was a simplified example of a more complex version, and that one still doesn't work. I'm rephrasing it once I have found a simplification that actually gives literally the same error. Sorry!

Comment: I realised too late that the actual problem I was trying to solve happened when using a derived instance rather than just the combination. The question is now updated to reflect this.

Comment: I like `this.type` because it says what I want it to say, that the subgraph returns an identically-typed graph. However, I run into a lot of problems with the builders that are used to construct automata in that case. But that's a separate question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there's no sense in writing `val aut: Automaton with Graphlike[Automaton]` since `Automaton extends Graphlike[Automaton]` (so `Automaton with Graphlike[Automaton] =:= Automaton`).

<strike>Secondly, I guess you want `Graphlike`'s `Vertex` to be `State` in `Automaton`. So you should add `override type Vertex = State` to `Automaton`.</strike>

Thirdly, `Vertex` is a path-dependent type. `aut.Vertex` and `a.Vertex` (where `val a: Automaton = aut.subgraph(Set(aut.initialState))`) are different types. If you want `subgraph` to accept `Set[x.Vertex]` for different `x: Automaton` then you should modify its signature using type projection

```
def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[A#Vertex]): A
```

(The whole code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pKfCrEjDToOXi0e7fDEt7w)

Another way to modify the signature of `subgraph` is (as **@user** proposed)

```
def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[Vertex]): this.type
```

So you should either expand parameter type (from `Set[Vertex]` aka `Set[this.Vertex]` to `Set[A#Vertex]`) or narrow return type (from `A` to `this.type`).