# Building instances of `this.type` in Scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism, builder

I am working on a graph trait called `Graphlike` where I use dependent/associated types for the vertices. After [solving my polymorphism issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916960/how-to-combine-f-bounded-polymorphism-with-associated-types-in-scala), my implementation looks like this:

```scala
trait Graphlike {
  type Vertex

  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[Vertex]): this.type
}
```

I also have various kinds of abstract atomic-state automata, which of course behave like graphs:

```scala
trait Automaton extends Graphlike {
  type State
  type Vertex = State

  def states: Iterable[State]
  def initialState: State
  def getBuilder: AutomatonBuilder[this.type]


  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[Vertex]) = {
    val builder = getBuilder
    // Some logic to actually do something to the builder here
    builder.getAutomaton
  }
}

trait AutomatonBuilder[A <: Automaton] {
  def getAutomaton: A
}
```

However, when I try to actually implement a concrete automaton, I run into trouble:

```scala
class ConcreteAutomaton extends Automaton {
  type State = Int

  def states = List(1, 2, 3)
  def initialState = 1
  def getBuilder = new ConcreteAutomatonBuilder

}

class ConcreteAutomatonBuilder extends AutomatonBuilder[ConcreteAutomaton] {
  def getAutomaton = new ConcreteAutomaton
}

class UsesAutomataAsGraphs {
  val aut = new ConcreteAutomaton
  aut.subgraph(Set(aut.initialState)).subgraph(Set(aut.initialState))
}
```

gives:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/albin/Downloads/example/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /Users/albin/Downloads/example/src/main/scala/example/Example.scala:33:20: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : ConcreteAutomatonBuilder
[error]  required: AutomatonBuilder[ConcreteAutomaton.this.type]
[error] Note: ConcreteAutomaton >: ConcreteAutomaton.this.type (and ConcreteAutomatonBuilder <: AutomatonBuilder[ConcreteAutomaton]), but trait AutomatonBuilder is invariant in type A.
[error] You may wish to define A as -A instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]   def getBuilder = new ConcreteAutomatonBuilder
[error]                    ^
```

Following the suggestion and making A contravariant gives me other issues. It's also not really what I want; I *want* my builders to produce the exact same type of automaton.

Comment: `this.type` refers to the singleton type of the current instance. You can not create a new instance of the same type as the current instance. What you can want to do can be solved using **F-Bounded** or **typeclasses**, take a look to [this](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html)

Comment: Thank you; that's what I had originally, but I think I may have something that could work now. If I get it to work on the real-world code I'll add it as a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another answer here because it's significantly different from the other one and because it would get too big. This one uses typeclasses and implicit classes to do everything, and I feel it's safer, even though it may seem boilerplate-y and a little too much to you.

Instead of putting `subgraph` in the `Graphlike` trait, different objects do the subgraph method and construct new automatons. An implicit class provides the `subgraph` method because I couldn't prove that `G` was the type of `this` in the `Graphlike` trait itself.

Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bYTXEzS3T6uNMShDIjQghA

```
trait Graphlike {
  type Vertex
}
trait Automaton extends Graphlike {
  type State
  type Vertex = State

  def states: Iterable[State]
  def initialState: State
}
class ConcreteAutomaton extends Automaton {
  type State = Int

  def states = List(1, 2, 3)
  def initialState = 1
}

trait AutomatonBuilder[+A <: Automaton] {
  def getAutomaton: A
}
class ConcreteAutomatonBuilder extends AutomatonBuilder[ConcreteAutomaton] {
  def getAutomaton = new ConcreteAutomaton
}


trait Subgraph[G <: Graphlike] {
  def subgraph(graph: G)(selectedVertices: Set[graph.Vertex]): G
}
trait AutomatonSubgraph[A <: Automaton] extends Subgraph[A] {
  protected def newBuilder: AutomatonBuilder[A]
  def subgraph(automaton: A)(selectedVertices: Set[automaton.Vertex]): A = {
    val builder = newBuilder
    //Do stuff to the builder here
    builder.getAutomaton
  }
}
implicit object ConcreteAutomatonSubgraph extends AutomatonSubgraph[ConcreteAutomaton] {
  protected def newBuilder = new ConcreteAutomatonBuilder()
}

implicit class Subgraphable[+G <: Graphlike](graph: G)(implicit sub: Subgraph[G]) {
  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[graph.Vertex]): G = sub.subgraph(graph)(selectedVertices)
}

class UsesAutomataAsGraphs {
  val aut = new ConcreteAutomaton
  val x = aut.subgraph(Set(aut.initialState)).subgraph(Set(aut.initialState))
}
```

Another approach that stays more faithful to your original design but I don't like: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/AfKX5cpbSXqrqesT4rsUvA

Comment: Thank you! I'll think about this and about how much refactoring I want to do, but I see the merit of this solution.

My problem during this whole refactoring is that different part of the code base will interact in surprising ways with the changes I am making in a way that that I can't at all predict.

Comment: Try the second way if you wish (the link's at the very bottom)

Comment: A quck follow-up question: would I need to add double copies for _every_ method in Automaton?

Comment: Only the ones that return `A` or something like that. If you have a `union` method or something that requires constructing an automaton of the same type, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

"Building instances of `this.type`" sounds strange. Anyway:

```
trait Graphlike {
  type Vertex

  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[Vertex]): this.type
}

trait Automaton extends Graphlike {
  type State
  type Vertex = State

  def states: Iterable[State]
  def initialState: State
  def getBuilder: AutomatonBuilder[this.type]

  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[Vertex]): this.type = {
    val builder = getBuilder
    // Some logic to actually do something to the builder here
    builder.getAutomaton
  }
}

trait AutomatonBuilder[A <: Automaton] {
  def getAutomaton: A
}

class ConcreteAutomaton extends Automaton {
  type State = Int

  def states = List(1, 2, 3)
  def initialState = 1
  def getBuilder = new ConcreteAutomatonBuilder[this.type](this)   
}

class ConcreteAutomatonBuilder[A <: Automaton with Singleton](a: A) extends AutomatonBuilder[A] {
  def getAutomaton = a
}
```

It's also strange that `Automaton` knows about `AutomatonBuilder`.

Comment: Where would you have put the builder? Inside of `Automaton`? Basically, I am working in an existing codebase and that part of the design was there when I got there and I only added the graph trait.

Comment: I think the `getAutomaton` method in the builder is supposed to return a new automaton after it's done setting all the fields and stuff, so I'm not sure merely returning the same automaton used to construct it would work.

Comment: @user That's what it does, yes. I just used that as a quick work-around for the example.

Comment: @albins I was just commenting on how the builder here returns A instead of a new automaton

Answer (score 1):

Following Dmytro Mitin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61917595/11882002) on the other question, you can do this, by making subgraph accept `Set[A#Vertex]` instead of `Set[this.Vertex]`. You can't use `this.type` as I suggested in my answer there because your original automaton that you're getting a subgraph from may implement all kinds of stuff that your builder can't possibly know about.

```
trait Graphlike[G <: Graphlike[G]] {
  type Vertex

  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[G#Vertex]): G
}

trait Automaton[A <: Automaton[A]] extends Graphlike[A] {
  type State
  type Vertex = State

  def getBuilder: AutomatonBuilder[A]
  def states: Iterable[State]
  def initialState: State

  def subgraph(selectedVertices: Set[A#Vertex]): A = {
    val builder = getBuilder
    // Some logic to actually do something to the builder here
    builder.addVertices(selectedVertices) //Example

    builder.getAutomaton
  }
}

trait AutomatonBuilder[A <: Automaton[A]] {
  def getAutomaton: A
  //example
  val verts = Set[A#Vertex]()
  def addVertices(s: Set[A#Vertex]): Unit = verts ++ s
}

class ConcreteAutomaton extends Automaton[ConcreteAutomaton] {
  type State = Int

  def states = List(1, 2, 3)
  def initialState = 1
  val getBuilder = new ConcreteAutomatonBuilder
}

class ConcreteAutomatonBuilder extends AutomatonBuilder[ConcreteAutomaton] {
  def getAutomaton = new ConcreteAutomaton
}

class UsesAutomataAsGraphs {
  val aut: ConcreteAutomaton = new ConcreteAutomaton
  aut.subgraph(Set(aut.initialState)).subgraph(Set(aut.initialState))
}
```